# WebAPI hangs indefinitely when receiving a POST with incorrect Content-Length in header

Tags: http-headers, asp.net-web-api

I have a project set up using ASP.NET WebAPI on top of Azure, and am having a problem whenever I try to make an HTTP Post where the content-length is too long in the header.

Normally I would've just ignored this problem, because you should be correctly setting the content-length on POST, but it turns out that when this happens, it causes the session to hang indefinitely, and then the Azure emulator crashes.

I have a custom JSON Formatter which extends MediaTypeFormatter, and I set a breakpoint on the first line of my implementation of OnReadFromStreamAsync().  However, the breakpoint is never hit because the hangup happens before ever hitting the JSON Deserializer.

I really have no idea where this hanging is occurring from because I receive no exception, just an indefinite hang and occasional Azure emulator crash.

Thank you in advance for any help or insight you might provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug.  The good thing is that you can get updated developer bits form codeplex.

There is a chance what your experiencing is related to one of these:

- [WebAPI: Stream uploading under webhost is not working](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/61)
- [DevDiv 388456 -- WebHost should not use Transfer-Encoding chunked when
  content length is known](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/06f52b894414#src/System.Web.Http.WebHost/HttpControllerHandler.cs).
- [Zero ContentLength without content type header in body is throwing](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/4c8548f5bc81)

If the updated bits don't fix your problem I suggest you try the standard media formatters to rule in/out your formatter.  Failing that, then  submit an issue.